# Running a Unity simulation with very low frames

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm doing a machine learning simulation in Unity and I just needed some reassurance of my logic. All the physics events happen in FixedUpdate() and so from what I understand, fluctuations in the frame rate won't affect my results as the correct number of physics calls will be made each cycle (I'm setting the timescale ridiculously high). Does this apply when the frame rate is really low, say 1-5 fps? Can I be guaranteed that the correct number of physics steps will be called as long as I can maintain a frame rate of 1 or above?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need to have a framerate of 1 for it to work. The physics' loop and the display loop (`FixedUpdate()` vs `Update()`) are independent of each other. Even if you have a below 1 FPS framerate your physics updates should still apply correctly, it will just do multiple physics steps to "catch up" before it renders the next display frame. See [this article from the unity documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) for more information about the order things get called on.

[image]

Comment: So i'll never 'lose' physics steps? For instance, if the timescale is set so high that the performance of my computer becomes a factor, that is, the time allocated for the physics step is not enough to do all the calculations?

Comment: So long as you do not modify the position of a `RigidBody` outside of the physics update loop you will never loose any "physics frames". If you do modify the position of a game object with a `RigidBody` you could get incorrect physics calculations. Either increase the value of `Maximum Allowed Timestep` in the [Time Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TimeManager.html) to give physics more time to catch up or rewrite your code so only ever move a `RigidBody` object during the update frame ...

Comment: **Important Note:** It does not need to be a `Update()` call that causes the move,  If you have child objects with a `RigidBody` and you have a animation on a parent you may move `RigidBody` during the animation update.